# Plesk Root Username and Password for SSH

Tags: ssh

In Plesk, where do I find the root username and password for SSH?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Plesk doesn't touch the root user. When it's installed it creates the admin user for it's own user. You might be able to run `sudo su -` as admin or another user and reset the root password that way. Otherwise, you'll have to use a recovery CD and reset the root password that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default admin user name is called admin and the password can be found in this path:

```
/etc/psa/.psa.shadow
```

Comment: That is the password used for the Plesk Control Panel. I certainly don't believe it uses this file for SSH.

Comment: The admin user exists in /etc/password and /etc/shadow as well, however Plesk keeps it in plain text in /etc/psa/.psa.shadow as it's used for connecting to mysql as well.